# I need to know if there is a way to show older rss feed items/posts

Tags: facebook, rss, feed

Basically, I need to know if there is a way to show older rss feed items/posts. For example, my facebook rss feed only shows 10 items, how would I get it to show more?

Comment: If the RSS feed provider doesn’t offer a way to “ask” for older data, then not at all. RSS is designed to be a “snapshot” of current content, and not a “database” that you can search through to get past data.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get this data from providers such as [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) who might have been fetching the feed's content for a long time.